# Как проверить, новый покупатель или нет в WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне необходимо проверять новый покупатель или нет в магазине на WooCommerce. Я пишу следующий код:

```php
function renderCustomerIsNewField($order){
    $customer_has_existing_orders  = wc_get_orders(
        array(
            'customer_id' => $order->get_user_id(),
            'status' => 'completed',
            'limit' => 2
        )
    );
    
    $markData = ( count($customer_has_existing_orders) )
        ? array('status-processing', 'Returning customer')
        : array('status-on-hold', 'New Customer');
    ?>
    <p>
        <mark class="order-status <?php echo $markData[0]; ?>">
            <span> <?php echo$markData[1]; ?></span>
        </mark>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

В коде проверяю пользователя по id, если есть заказ со статусом completed и мне необходимо, что б метка Returning ставилась только если заказов со статусом completed не меньше 2х, для этого пишу 'limit' => 2, однако это не срабатывает. Подскажите, как можно сделать проверку, что именно не меньше 2х завершенных заказов у одного пользователя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно получить все заказы в статусе completed, а потом посчитать количество и сравнить это количество с 2. Limit ограничивает в запросе **количество получаемых результатов**, вам же нужно проверить все заказы, поэтому нужно указать limit => -1.
Соответственно, условие должно выглядеть так: ( count($customer_has_existing_orders) >= 2 )
В целом код должен быть такой (не проверял):

```php
function renderCustomerIsNewField($order){
    $customer_has_existing_orders  = wc_get_orders(
        array(
            'customer_id' => $order->get_user_id(),
            'status' => 'completed',
            'limit' => -1
        )
    );
    
    $markData = ( count($customer_has_existing_orders) >= 2 )
        ? array('status-processing', 'Returning customer')
        : array('status-on-hold', 'New Customer');
    ?>
    <p>
        <mark class="order-status <?php echo $markData[0]; ?>">
            <span> <?php echo $markData[1]; ?></span>
        </mark>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: В целом да, у меня получилось, единственное, хотелось бы добавить, что проверка count($customer_has_existing_orders) >= 2 так не сработает, вначале count($customer_has_existing_orders) нужно привести к int. У меня это выглядит так (int)count($customer_has_existing_orders) >= 2 :)